# Haphazard Scrolling on double click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get scrolling right on  div tags by clicking on list of anchor tags using jquery.

```
enter code here
        function scrollThere(targetElement, speed) {
       // initiate an animation to a certain page element:
      $('html, body , #side').stop().animate(
      { scrollTop: targetElement.offset().top }, // move window so target 
      element is at top of window
      speed, // speed in milliseconds
     'swing' // easing
      ); // end animate
    } // end scrollThere function definition


     //--- START NAV-ITEM CLICK EVENTS ---//
    // when the user clicks a nav item:
    $("#leftSidebar ul li a").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // don't jump like a typical html anchor

    // find the index of the "#" character in the href string...
    var startOfName = $(this).attr('href').indexOf("#"),
    // ...then use it as the argument in the slice() method (add 1 so you 
    don't include the # character).
    clickRef = $(this).attr('href').slice(startOfName + 1),
     targetEl = $('a[name=' + clickRef + ']'); // select the element this 
     link is pointing to

    // scroll there smoothly:
    scrollThere(targetEl, 400);

    });
```

The problem is that when I click on a link twice,it takes me to the top of the page and the scrolling messes up too.The scrolling for some reason dosent work properly as the size of div tags increase.Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/60tp46y3/18/ showing the problem.Ideally on clicking respective links on left the right section should scroll to the appropriate id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adapted your code. It's working now.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/t0of2kzp/
```

The error was, that you didn't checked the current scroll position of the container, which contains all other elements.

```
// targetElement is the div surrounding the target a tag.
var postionOfTargetElement = targetElement.offset().top;
// That's the main container
var scrollPosition = targetElement.parent().scrollTop();
// Here we calculate the real top position with respecting the main containers scroll position.
var topTarget = postionOfTargetElement + scrollPosition;
```

Comment: Perfect!Worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)